# Pass data upstream to app component

Tags: angular

Is it possible to pass data two or more levels upstream from Child Component to App Component?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a shared service like explained in https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html

Provide the service once at the root component and it is avialable throughout the application and you can use it (for example also with observables) to communicate in both directions, similar to an event bus.